# MySQL/MariaDB trigger to redirect query to another table

Tags: mysql, wordpress, triggers, mariadb

I'm trying to migrate from a custom CMS to Wordpress, but retain as much as possible from the structure of the old CMS. The problem is the old one had separate DB table for media and wordpress stores media alongside posts, in the wp_posts table.

In the old cms, images had independent IDs from the post ID's and I would like to keep this structure. (10TB of media, 500K articles :) in the DB ).

I'm trying to make a trigger that, when a query hits the wp_posts table with "type=attachment", fetches the result from the media table and returns it, ignoring the results from the wp_posts table.

No luck yet...

Has anyone did this before? All (almost)successful examples online are on PostgreSQL...

Thanks,
Silviu

Comment: If your aim was to move away from a custom CMS to a standard CMS ... If you do this you will again endup with a custom CMS. Instead, can I suggest you just work on some code to migrate the custom data into the standard Wordpress database

Comment: *I'm trying to make a trigger that, when a query hits the wp_posts table with "type=attachment", fetches the result from the media table and returns it, ignoring the results from the wp_posts table.* o_O Do you mean that you want to create trigger for to effect the SELECT query output?

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I forgot triggers are not for select...
Will try to find other way to solve this.
Also, @RiggsFolly is right...

Comment: I second @Akina, triggers are for data modification queries, not for selects. You can use a view to "hide" a table. But to RiggsFolly's point: you would then be using a custom CMS, not wordpress.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.